# Can weapons be destroyed?

Tags: starbound

Can weapons be destroyed in combat? I have a feeling I keep fat-fingering and accidentally dropping my weapon when I have to move around a lot in combat, but I can't find my weapon on the ground after combat.

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to Arqade. These are both fine questions, but they're mostly unrelated, and should really have been asked separately.

Comment: Indeed, if you want to ask both of these questions, I would suggest editing this question to make it focus on whether or not weapons can be destroyed, and make a seprate question for whether or not they can be poisoned.  Both of these are good questions, and deserve their own separate attention.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the poison question into a separate thread. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145842/can-weapons-be-poisoned-after-finding-creating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first question, weapons don't degrade over time or get destroyed in combat.  Even picks, which DO lose their quality over time, never fully get destroyed, simply getting worse with wear.

It's possible you did drop your weapon, or otherwise switched weapons/hit a button to toss your weapon, and then it went into your inventory as other items droppd in battle took up the slot that it formerly was in.

But weapons themselves do not break.

Comment: Then where do they go? Am I accidentally hitting a keyboard shortcut that completely trashes the item for good? I checked my inventory--I have what appears to be a backpack and maybe a sack, neither of which contain the lost items.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  If this information is incorrect or missing info, please comment on it. ( I wouldn't know as I have yet to play this game)

Comment: @David It's possible it got glitched out of existence, since this is still a beta.  If that is the case, I am very sorry. :( It's also possible, if you dropped the item and died, that it de-spawned from where it dropped.  Without being able to see what happened though, I can only speculate.

Comment: @Zibbobz thanks--FWIW, I didn't downvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

"Loose" items in Starbound (items that can be picked up by moving near them) will vanish after a timeout, and in the current version of the beta (check the time stamp, future readers) that timeout is *not very long*. If you fumble Q an item and it falls down a cave, it's very likely to expire before you get down to it.

This is also a concern if you disturb fine sand or gravel with ore and capsules - the ore will become loose and the capsules will break, creating loose pixels, and you have to scramble through the falling sand to get to them before they expire.

ETA: As of January 26, a patch has been released which prevents items dropped by players from timing out.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was hitting the **Q** key since my weapon was armed at slot **1**. It doesn't explain why my weapon was missing altogether, but I think it's the best explanation of why it left my inventory!

Comment: Not the most embarassing mistake to make.  See - Me not realizing you had to hit "e" to use things and being unable to escape my spaceship.

Comment: Also, I still think you probably dropped it in the middle of battle, and either never picked it up, lost it in your inventory, or accidentally stored it somewhere.