# Can weapons be poisoned after finding/creating?

Tags: starbound

Can weapons be poisoned after crafting/finding them? The weapon I lost in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145836/can-weapons-be-destroyed-or-poisoned) was a very effective poisoned spear, and I'm wondering what happened or if I can get a spear and re-poison it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, no. Weapons' stats are locked in on creation. The only way to change them is to directly edit your save file.

But, the game is currently in the very early stages, so such a feature might eventually be added.

Comment: Are there already save file editors out there? I found a player editor, but it's basically just descriptions

Comment: @David No idea, sorry. I haven't really looked into save editing much, especially given that the save file format is doubtlessly changing most every update, and also saves are being wiped occasionally.